# Adding custom primaryMeasureAxis with Flutter charts

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do TimeSeriesChart with the Y-axis (vertical axis) has custom labels.

I can verify that the strings ('`final List<dynamic> string = data.data['options'];`') holds the values I expect. And I can even reference them like strings[0], but when I do `strings[value.toInt()]` it throws a `RangeError`.

See this piece of code.
Where I initialize 'final label' I have two lines of codes defining a `BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec`.

The first line is what I am trying to do. I want to use the `value` to lookup a string in the `strings[]`.

I can do `((num value) =>  'MyValue: ${string[0]}')` which works just fine.
I can do `((num value) =>  'MyValue: ${string}')` just to output all the values on each "step".

So, basically I can verify that `string` actually hold the values I expect, and I can access the values, but if I try to lookup a value, `((num value) =>  'MyValue: ${string[value.toInt()]}')` then it breaks with this RangeError.

```
Widget _buildChart(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
    final List<dynamic> string = data.data['options'];

    final labels =
    charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num value) =>  'MyValue: ${string[value.toInt()]}');
    // charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num value) =>  'MyValue: ${string[0]}')

    var chart = charts.TimeSeriesChart(seriesList,
        // Sets up a currency formatter for the measure axis.
        primaryMeasureAxis: new charts.NumericAxisSpec(tickFormatterSpec: labels),
        animate: animate,
        // Optionally pass in a [DateTimeFactory] used by the chart. The factory
        // should create the same type of [DateTime] as the data provided. If none
        // specified, the default creates local date time.
        dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory());

    return new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
          child: chart,
        ));
  }
```

I expected each 'value' that I put into `((num value) => '$strings[value.toInt()])` would return a string from strings[].

Instead I get:

> flutter: The following RangeError was thrown during performLayout():
>   flutter: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..1,
>   inclusive: 2

Comment: I'd guess that the chart has figured out that it needs ticks on the Y axis of, say, 0, 1 and 2. It's therefore calling the formatter spec closure in order to get the '2' tick formatted, but your list of labels isn't long enough (doesn't contain 2).

Comment: Yes, that would be the obvious (or sane) explanation. What bugs me is that I am able to verify the "ticks" needed and the labels available match.

Comment: Any progress finding the issue?

Comment: No solution sadly, but I will try your diagnostics later tonight. I have not had the time I hoped for.

One thing I have found on the interwebs, is that the error is usually associated with a ListView.builder() that has no itemCount parameter passed in its constructor. So maybe something goes south inside the package. Have not investigated further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try expanding your tick formatter closure so that you get more diagnostics:

```
final labels = charts.BasicNumericTickFormatterSpec((num value) {
  var index = value.floor();
  print('--- tick for $value in $string with $index ---');
  return (index < string.length)
      ? 'MyValue: ${string[index]}'
      : 'overflow ${string.length} $index';
});
```